# C++ linked lists read access violation

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I'm currently studying linked lists and I came upon this problem and I still can't find a solution.

This is how a basic node looks like.

```
struct node {
    int data;
    node *next;
};
```

I'm trying to swap the position of the first and the last node with this function.

```
void swap_first_and_last() {
    node *temp = new node;
    node *temp2 = new node;

    temp->data = head->data;
    temp->next = NULL;

    temp2->next = head->next;
    temp2->data = tail->data;

    head = temp2;
    tail = temp;
}
```

The error I'm getting is: Exception thrown: read access violation, this->tail was nullptr.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `temp2->data = tail->data;`  What's the value of tail?  (hint: it's in the exception message)

Comment: Do you buy two brand new cars when you need to swap positions of a Toyota and a Honda in a parking lot?

Comment: Tail was initiated before and it should have a value associated with it so I don't understand why I'm getting nullptr.

Comment: @n.m. Yeah, I suppose I could do it with just one tmp node.

Comment: So you buy just one new car. A Toyota or a Honda? A Ford perhaps?

Comment: I make a temporary parking spot where I park one car while I park the other one in the former spot.

Comment: @kruzics alternatively you could avoid making any new nodes, and just swap the data in the nodes ... half the lines, and 100% less calls to new (which means no new cars!)

Comment: If you want to continue that analogy, a car is an object (big and heavy, creating a new one costs a lot) and a parking spot is a pointer. You only need a temporary pointer, not a temporary object, and you don't want any `new`, for a lot of reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You havn't deleted head & tail.
- Assuming `tail` is the last, there is somewhere a `node::next` pointing to it, and you didn't changed it to point to `temp`
- What if the list is empty? you didn't checked if `head` or `tail` is null.

**Edit** added fixed method

```
void swap_first_and_last() 
{
    //if there is less than 2 nodes - finished.
    if(!head || !tail || head==tail) return; 
    node *temp = new node;
    node *temp2 = new node;
    node *temp3;

    temp->data = head->data;
    temp->next = NULL;

    temp2->next = head->next;
    temp2->data = tail->data;

    temp3 = head;
    head = temp2;
    delete temp3; //delete old head
    temp3 = tail;
    //find the tail previous
    for(tail=head; tail->next!=temp3;tail=tail->next);
    //make tail previous point to tail
    tail->next = temp;
    tail = temp;//now it will point to new tail...
    delete temp3;//delete old tail
}
```

A better solution:

```
void swap_first_and_last() 
{
    node *temp;
    //if there is less than 2 nodes - finished.
    if(!head || !tail || head==tail) return; 
    for(temp=head; temp->next!=tail;temp=temp->next);
    temp->next = head; //set tail precedor's next to point to head, prepere for head = tail
    tail->next = head->next; //set tail's next to point head->next, prepere for head = tail 
    head = tail; //set tail as head
    tail = temp->next; //set old head as tail
    tail->next = NULL; // tail next is always null (was point to the 2nd).
}
```

Comment: @kruzics added fixed method

Answer (score 0):

```
//              V----- where does tail get initialized?
temp2->data = tail->data;
```

When `swap_first_and_last` is called, but `tail` hasn't been initialized, just as the runtime says: you're going to have a bad time.

You can either -

- Make sure that `tail` is initialized with a value before calling
  `swap_first_and_last`
- Check to see if `tail` is initialized before
  trying to do any read access on it.

I think the latter is a better option.

```
if (head) {
    temp->data = head->data;
}

if (tail) {
    temp2->data = tail->data;
}
```

A question you should ask yourself - *why don't I put this initialization in the constructor of `node`*?

Comment: I don't quite understand yet, but I'll try to figure it out, thank you!

Comment: I understand you've already acknowledged other answers, but you're welcome to let me know where you are losing me and I'll try my best to help you understand :D

Answer (score 0):

Your new to C++ so I understand this isn't particularly easy to grasp, but once you get the hang of it you will understand the comments above.

head and tail are pointers `node *head;` so you don't need to create copies of the objects that they point to.

head points to a block of memory that has the content (data = 42; next = tail) and tail points to a block of memory that holds (7 and null).  You can copy head into `temp` and tail into `temp2` and then copy them back into `tail` and `head` but why?  What do you gain by creating copies of the memory blocks, apart from memory leaks?  You don't care about the blocks of memory, you don't want to move them, you don't want to change them all you want to do is change which pointer points to which block of memory.

```
node* pTemp = head;
head = tail;
tail = head;
```

Unfortunately this breaks your list because now `head->next = null` so you just need to repair that:

```
pTemp = head->next;  // Which should always be null.
head->next = tail->next;
tail->next = pTemp;
```

Now if you stick that in a little function that takes the two pointers as parameters you have a block of code that can switch any two given nodes in your list, meaning sorting your list becomes a lot easier.

Comment: Just to be clear this is a simplified answer, there are other aspects you should be aware of, such as parameter checking, but it should sole your immediate problem.